# Adding a check box using MERN

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am form where i am trying to add a check box for gender selection. I have tried everything but with no result.
Here is my code about the checkbox and a picture of my form

```
          <div className="input-field col s12">
            <input
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.gender}
              error={errors.gender}
              id="gender"
              type="checkbox"
              className={classnames("", {
                invalid: errors.amka
              })}
            />
            <label htmlFor="gender"><b className="black-text text-darken-1">Gender:</b></label>
            <span className="red-text">{errors.gender}</span>
            <br></br>
          </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf5iA.png)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first of all you should not use chekckbox for gender selection unless there is very specific reason for that.

Here is the code for checkbox.

```
<div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="checkbox"
      id="checkbox"
      checked={value}
      value={value}
      onChange={e => {
        // perform the function onChange
      }}
    />
    <label for="checkbox">My Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f5q3n8?file=src/App.js